# How can you put html inside a php variable?

Tags: php, html

None of the other methods work so could you please help? Here is my code:

```
<?php
include("db.php");
If(isset($_SESSION['name']))
{
$main = "<h2>hey</h2>";
} 
else
{
$main = "<h2>welcome</h2>"
}
?>


<html>
<body>
<?php echo $main;?>
</body>
</html>

//db.php consists of

<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("notes");
echo mysql_error();
session_start();
?>
```

Whenever I run the code it always shows: welcome. No matter if I'm logged in or logged out of my website.

Comment: where did you set session variable `$_SESSION['name']` ?

Answer (score -1):

Your html is looks good but 
It seems that you did not set `session_start()` at the top of your php file or you did not set session variable.

try like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['name']))
{
$main = "<h2>hey</h2>";
} 
else
{
$main = "<h2>welcome</h2>"
}
?>


<html>
<body>
<?php echo $main;?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have done both in my real code i was just givin a summarized version. Is there any thing else i can do?

Comment: @webmaster: if you have `session_start()` in all pages where you have used session and set `$_SESSION['name']` then there is no reason to happen this

Comment: this is the file that i have included in all my pages       <?php
 mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
 mysql_select_db("notes");
 echo mysql_error();
 session_start();
?>

Comment: i think your set of session variable script is not executed before you are visiting this page. you need to execute `$_SESSION['name']="username"` before viewing this page

Comment: That might be it but when the user logs in , it also executes that.

Comment: then first login and then try to view this page

Comment: i have multiple times; i have been working on this for several days